# Does the contractionary monetary effect of tax conpensate for its deadweight loss?

Tags: inflation, taxation

We all know that if the government impose a tax on a product, then tax revenue is less than loss in consumer and producer surplus. This is known as deadweight loss.

We also know that taxing is a contractionary fiscal policy. Imposing a tax reduces inflation. So the **real** value of the social welfare is actually increased in this way.

As a result, some of the deadweight loss is conpensated by reduction in inflation.

**Is this line of reasoning valid?** If it is true, then does the reduction in inflation completely conpensate the loss or only partially conpensate it? If this is not true, what's wrong?